# Reemplazar un valor NA concreto

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente df

```
datos2<-data.frame(
  col1=c("verde","amarillo ","azul","verde","rojo","verde","rojo","amarillo","verde","amarillo"),
  col2=c("R","A","V3","V3","RI","TR","RA","VQ","V3","A1"),
  col3=c(1,NA,4,222,NA,NA,NA,34,NA,4)
)
```

```
        col1 col2 col3
1      verde    R    1
2  amarillo     A   NA
3       azul   V3    4
4      verde   V3  222
5       rojo   RI   NA
6      verde   TR   NA
7       rojo   RA   NA
8   amarillo   VQ   34
9      verde   V3   NA
10  amarillo   A1   4
```

Si se cumple que la col2 es igual a v3 y la col3 tiene valor NA
entonces reemplazo ese Na por 9000. El resto lo dejo como está
(Es decir, modificar el NA de la fila 9)

Habia pensado en esto y en algunas modificaciones del mismo pero no lo consigo.

```
datos2$col3 <- ifelse(datos2$col2=="V3" & is.na(datos2$col3) ,
                      datos2$col3[datos2$col2=="V3"]<- 9000, datos2$col3)
```

Comment: Probaste `ifelse(datos2$col2=="V3" & is.na(datos2$col3), 9000, datos2$col3)` ? Creo que funciona. No es necesario asignar con `<-` dentro del ifelse, es una función vectorizada que crea un vector nuevo, entonces solo asignas para reemplazar `col3` en el df.

Comment: Si, funciona bien

Comment: Una forma alternativa que para mi gusto es más eficiente: `datos2$col3[datos2$col2=="V3" & is.na(datos2$col3)] <- 9000`

Comment: Muchas gracias. Lo he modificado un poco para que localice una palabra en la frase con grepl. Funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo pongo para que quede como respuesta

```
datos2$col3<-ifelse(datos2$col2=="V3" & is.na(datos2$col3), 9000, datos2$col3)
```